# What does it mean 'the observer' in Quantum Physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, observers

Is it only necessary a human consciousness? A measurement device?
Can it be said that any of them cause the wave function collapse?

Comment: If I could answer this in a definite manner, I would be collecting Nobel's every year for the rest of my life...